# match multiple digits with str.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is returning as empty when attempting to replace it with specified digits from the string.

```
const input = 4w12d3h;
let days = 0;

if (/d/.test(input)) {
    days = input.replace(/.*(\d*)d.*/, '$1');
}
```

I expect the output to be '12' but it returns as ''. If I instead do (\d) or (\d+) it will return as the digit before the letter (2), but I need to match as many digits as exist before the letter.

Comment: Use `days = input.match(/(\d+)d/)[0]`

Comment: The greedy .* is what is screwing you up. It seems like you are using replace where you should just be matching.

Comment: Removing the greedy .* fixed it immediately and was a silly mistake on my part. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` also to get the desired output

```js
const input = '4w12d3h';
let days = 0;

if (/d/.test(input)) {
    days = input.match(/(\d+)d/);
}
console.log(days[1])
```